# What file types does Finder search the *content* of?

Tags: finder, search, text, binary

I noticed that the `Search` bar in Finder not only searches the filenames, but also the contents of some types of files. It appears that the search includes the content of all text files, and even some binary file types like `.pdf`, but excludes the contents of other file types like `.docx` or `.xls`.

Just exactly what file types are included in this content search? Does this search simply execute a `grep` command, and if so, what would that be?

[image]